# Clean Messy Strings in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a messy inventory list (around 10K) to clean and I am some problems of using regular expression in Python to achieve this. Here is a small sample of my list:

```
product_pool=["#101 BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA", 
              "#W65066CS - Cell phone, Triangle wand & 5 sections lip gloss", 
              "(Archived)S.O.S. Steel Wool Soap Pads", 
              "(ARCHIVED) HTH Spa pH Increaser",
              "****GLUE STICKS",
              "-20Â°F Splash Windshield Washer Fluid",
              "01127 â€“ Fingâ€™rs Mighty Drop, 3g",
              "10-01130-Brush On Nail Glue (Three Bond TB1743)",
              "AveenoÂ® Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products"]
```

Ideally, I would like to remove symbols like `#, *, Â®, â€“, Â°F`, numbers like `101, 10-01130-, 01127`, and worlds in parentheses `(Archived), (Three Bond TB1743)`. And the final output would look like

```
product_pool=["BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA", 
              "Cell phone, Triangle wand 5 sections lip gloss", 
              "S.O.S. Steel Wool Soap Pads", 
              "HTH Spa pH Increaser",
              "GLUE STICKS",
              "Splash Windshield Washer Fluid",
              "Fing'rs Mighty Drop",
              "Brush On Nail Glue",
              "Aveeno Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products"]
```

My approach is to split the product by symbols I do not want to keep and then keep all the letters. But this approach does not seem work very well. So I appreciate any suggestions!

```
for product in product_pool:
    product_split=re.split(' |, |[) |* |-]', product)
    print ' '.join(ch for ch in product_split if ch.isalpha())
```

And the outputs look:

```
BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA
Cell phone Triangle wand sections lip gloss
Steel Wool Soap Pads (S.O.S. is missing)
HTH Spa pH Increaser
GLUE STICKS
Splash Windshield Washer Fluid
Mighty Drop (Fing'rs is missing)
Brush On Nail Glue Bond
Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products (Aveeno is missing)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
product_pool=["#101 BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA", 
              "#W65066CS - Cell phone, Triangle wand & 5 sections lip gloss", 
              "(Archived)S.O.S. Steel Wool Soap Pads", 
              "(ARCHIVED) HTH Spa pH Increaser",
              "****GLUE STICKS",
              "-20Â°F Splash Windshield Washer Fluid",
              "01127 â€“ Fingâ€™rs Mighty Drop, 3g",
              "10-01130-Brush On Nail Glue (Three Bond TB1743)",
              "AveenoÂ® Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products"]
```

Still a few extra spaces, but this could be one way to go about it.

```
import string
goodChars = string.ascii_letters + '.' + ' '
cleaned = [''.join(i for i in word if i in goodChars) for word in product_pool]

>>> cleaned
[' BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA',
 'WCS  Cell phone Triangle wand   sections lip gloss',
 'ArchivedS.O.S. Steel Wool Soap Pads',
 'ARCHIVED HTH Spa pH Increaser',
 'GLUE STICKS',
 'F Splash Windshield Washer Fluid',
 '  Fingrs Mighty Drop g',
 'Brush On Nail Glue Three Bond TB',
 'Aveeno Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products']
```

You can play around with what characters you want to keep, check out [string constants](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) for things like `string.punctuation`, `string.ascii_letters`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. It seems like this clean-up requires multiple steps. Will check `string.ascii_letters + '.' + ' '`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) substitution with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re

pattern = '[^a-zA-Z\s]|(?i)archived'
results = [re.sub(pattern, '', s).strip() for s in product_pool]
# ['BUMP STOPPER RAZOR BUMP TREATMENT SENSITIVE SKIN FORMULA',
#  'WCS  Cell phone Triangle wand   sections lip gloss',
#  'SOS Steel Wool Soap Pads',
#  'HTH Spa pH Increaser',
#  'GLUE STICKS',
#  'F Splash Windshield Washer Fluid',
#  'Fingrs Mighty Drop g',
#  'Brush On Nail Glue Three Bond TB',
#  'Aveeno Continuous Protection Sunblock Spray Products']
```

The regex pattern `[^...]` matches anything that isn't in `...`. You can then use `re.sub` to replace all these matches with empty strings, effectively deleting them. The second term of the pattern matches the `archived` chunks, and the `(?i)` tells it to ignore case for those.